# 1366 Incorrect integer value: Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, migration

I keep getting `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'stock'`

[image]

Here is how I migrate `stock`

`$table->integer('stock')->nullable()->default(0)->unsigned();`

Here is how I grab it to store into stock

`$inventory->stock       = $value[2];` // some data are ''= empty string

Is there a way to set a default value for it ?
How do I stop this error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the data before trying to save it. From your example, it looks like you'll have an integer value within a string, so you could do e.g. this:

```
$inventory->stock = ctype_digit($value[2]) ? $value[2] : 0;
```

If not 0, then null, or some other default value.

Or even this if you're sure about the values either being empty string or integers:

```
$inventory->stock = $value[2] ?: 0;
```

You could also probably just not add the stock if you don't have any, since you have a default for the column anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert the value into an integer. I personally like casting the most:

```
$inventory->stock = (int) $value[2];
```

However you can also use `intval($value[2])` or add zero: `$value[2] + 0`.

If you don't want to worry about it in the controller, create a mutator in the model:

```
public function setStockAttribute($value){
    $this->attributes['stock'] = (int) $value;
}
```

And you can just assign it like you used to:

```
$inventory->stock = $value[2];
```